# How to prove that $f(x,y)=x-y$ is one-to-one?

Tags: functions, proof-writing

Given $f: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f(x,y) = x-y$. How can I prove that the function is one to one?

I know that f(x,y)=x-y is a plane, and just by visualizing it I can see that it is one-to-one. But I'm confused as to how to prove this for a function in 3D. If it's just a 2D function, I could've showed that the equation can be solved uniquely for x. But for this one I'm stumped.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This function is not one to one at all. $f(2,1)=f(3,2)=f(4,3)=...$

Answer (score 3):

$$f(1,1)=f(2,2)\quad \text{so?}$$